# How to define the 'ImporError' in the graph-tool python module?

Tags: python, graph, graph-theory, graph-tool

I'm trying to use the `graph-tool` python module, which is really great by the way. To do so I have:

- downloaded version 2.2.30 (http://downloads.skewed.de/graph-tool/graph-tool-2.2.30.tar.bz2)
- followed the installation instructions (http://graph-tool.skewed.de/download)

to compile the module I had to use this option: `--with-sparsehash-prefix=google`. Then after a quite long compilation time I have checked the compilation with `make check` and everything seems okay.

However when I try to do the Quick Start (http://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/quickstart.html) I get this:

```
>>> from graph_tool.all import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graph_tool/all.py", line 34, in <module>
    from graph_tool.draw import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graph_tool/draw/__init__.py", line 770, in <module>
    from .cairo_draw import graph_draw, cairo_draw, get_hierarchy_control_points
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graph_tool/draw/cairo_draw.py", line 51, in <module>
    except ImporError:
NameError: name 'ImporError' is not defined
```

Can you explain me what is the issue and how to fix it please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo in the module. It was supposed to be `ImportError`, not `ImporError`. You can go to that particular line in the file and edit it.

Comment: Exactly, it works perfectly thanks. I will contact the developers of the graph-tool module to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed now in the new release.